# Using Javafx TimeLine In a Thread

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm trying to create an internet checker class, that will check the connection to a certain url and update the status property accordingly. To avoid ui freeze i want to use a thread, and a timer to recheck after a certain interval. Problem is the CHECK method call in the timeline keyframe is called from the FX thread still. How can i use a timeline inside a thread?

**CODE:**

```
public class InternetChecker {
    private String baseUrl;
    /***Properties***/
    private ObjectProperty<Status> status = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Status.ACTIVE);

    /****************************************************************
     **********                  CONSTRUCTORS            ************
     ****************************************************************/
    public InternetChecker(String baseUrl) {
        this(baseUrl, 1000);
    }

    public InternetChecker(String baseUrl, int millisCheckInterval) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        new Thread(() -> {
            Timeline timelineCheck = new Timeline();
            timelineCheck.getKeyFrames().add(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(millisCheckInterval), e -> {
                        check();
                    }));
            timelineCheck.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
            timelineCheck.play();
        }).start();
    }

    /*******************************
     * Will check if there is an internet connection present
     * and update the status accordingly
     *******************************/
    public void check() {
        // Check if base internet connection
        // is working, if it is we continue
        // to see if domain connection is working
        try {
            if ("127.0.0.1".equals(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress())) {
                setStatus(Status.INTERNET_DISCONNECTED);
                return;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // Check if base domain connection is working
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(baseUrl);
            final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            conn.getInputStream().close();
            setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            setStatus(Status.BASE_URL_UNREACHABLE);
        }
    }

    /****************************************************************
     **********                  ACCESSORS               ************
     ****************************************************************/

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Status> statusProperty() {
        return status;
    }

    private void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status.set(status);
    }

    /*******************************
     *  ACTIVE (Base url reachable)
     *  BASE_URL_UNREACHABLE (Internet available, but base url is unreachable)
     *  INTERNET_DISCONNECTED (Internet is not available)
     ********************************/
    public enum Status {
        ACTIVE,
        BASE_URL_UNREACHABLE,
        INTERNET_DISCONNECTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use a [`javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html) for this.

Comment: @Slaw
Could you provide me (In an answer) a proper way to use a ScheduledService for my case?

Comment: The `TimeLine` is meant to animate nodes, so it will run on the UI thread. For doing stuff on the background, while once in a while an update of the UI is needed read more on [JavaFX concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)

Comment: Thank you guys, i used a scheduledservice as Slaw suggested and it worked great. I had to wrap the setStatus method in a Platform#runLater call so i can add a listener to the status property to change a label in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to do a periodic *background* task that communicates with the *JavaFX Application Thread* it would be better to use a [`ScheduledService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html). This class executes a (new) [`Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) periodically using an `Executor` that can be defined by the developer. Note that `ScheduledService` extends `javafx.concurrent.Service`.

Here is a skeleton example of what you'd need to do to implement this:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.ScheduledService;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class ConnectionStatusService extends ScheduledService<Status> {

    // Property allows you to change the "baseUrl" between executions
    private final StringProperty baseUrl = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "baseUrl");

    // property getter and setters omitted...

    @Override
    protected Task<Status> createTask() {
        // creates a new Task and gives the current "baseUrl"
        // as an argument. This is called every cycle
        return new ConnectionStatusTask(getBaseUrl());
    }

    private static class ConnectionStatusTask extends Task<Status> {

        // A Task is a one-shot thing and its initial state should be
        // immutable (or at least encapsulated from external modification).
        private final String baseUrl;

        private ConnectionStatusTask(String baseUrl) {
            this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        }

        @Override
        protected Status call() throws Exception {
            // Do what you need to determine connection status
            return computedStatus;
        }
    }

}
```

Then you'd listen/bind to the [`lastValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html#lastValueProperty) property.

```
public void initService() {
    ConnectionStatusService service = new ConnectionStatusService();
    service.setBaseUrl(/* your URL */);
    service.setPeriod(Duration.seconds(1)); // run every 1 seconds
    service.lastValueProperty().addListener(/* your listener */); // or bind to this property

    // you may also want to add EventHandlers/Listeners to handle when the
    // service fails and such.
    service.start();
}
```

It's important you observe the `lastValue` property and not the `value` property. The reason is given in the Javadoc of `lastValue`:

> The last successfully computed value. During each iteration, the
>   "value" of the ScheduledService will be reset to null, as with any
>   other Service. The "lastValue" however will be set to the most
>   recently successfully computed value, even across iterations. It is
>   reset however whenever you manually call reset or restart.

I recommend reading the Javadoc of `Task`, `Service`, and `ScheduledService` for more information. All three of these classes implement the `javafx.concurrent.Worker` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You only want a single statement to be executed on the JavaFX application thread and that is `status.set(status);`. Since you're planing to run this statement with some delay in between, you can simply use `Platform.runLater` to do this.

As for repeatedly executing the check: [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is designed for this purpose.

```
public class InternetChecker implements Runnable {
    private final String baseUrl;
    /***Properties***/

    // use readonly wrapper here to restrict outside access to the property
    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Status> status = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(Status.ACTIVE);

    /****************************************************************
     **********                  CONSTRUCTORS            ************
     ****************************************************************/
    public InternetChecker(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    /*******************************
     * Will check if there is an internet connection present
     * and update the status accordingly
     *******************************/
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Check if base internet connection
        // is working, if it is we continue
        // to see if domain connection is working
        try {
            if ("127.0.0.1".equals(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress())) {
                setStatus(Status.INTERNET_DISCONNECTED);
                return;
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        // Check if base domain connection is working
        try {
            final URL url = new URL(baseUrl);
            final URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            conn.getInputStream().close();
            setStatus(Status.ACTIVE);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            setStatus(Status.BASE_URL_UNREACHABLE);
        }
    }

    /****************************************************************
     **********                  ACCESSORS               ************
     ****************************************************************/

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Status> statusProperty() {
        return status.getReadOnlyProperty​();
    }

    private void setStatus(final Status status) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> this.status.set(status));
    }

    /*******************************
     *  ACTIVE (Base url reachable)
     *  BASE_URL_UNREACHABLE (Internet available, but base url is unreachable)
     *  INTERNET_DISCONNECTED (Internet is not available)
     ********************************/
    public enum Status {
        ACTIVE,
        BASE_URL_UNREACHABLE,
        INTERNET_DISCONNECTED;
    }
}
```

```
InternetChecker checker = new InternetChecker(url);
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor​();

// use delay here to avoid race condition
executorService.scheduleAtFixedDelay(checker, 0, millisCheckInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Note that you need to shut down the service "manually" or use a `ThreadFactory` returning daemon threads:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor​(r -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the ReadOnlyObjectWrapper tip. Your answer is a bit cleaner too.